# LaTeX template for Springer economic journals?

Tags: document-classes, journal-publishing, springernature

In submission guidelines for Springer economic journals it is typically written that "We recommend using Springer Nature's LaTeX template". But in the template itself you can choose among different document classes:

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-aps]{sn-jnl}% American Physical Society (APS) Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-vancouver]{sn-jnl}% Vancouver Reference Style
```

What of these document classes is preferable for economic journals, if any?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I've never submitted anything to Springer, but I think that the `sn-jnl` option is the one they're suggesting.

Comment: It seems that, from the three choices, that only one is a style choice for reference type and the others may present math/phys equations better. For Econ there may need to be a survey of preferred Econ journals to see if a latex style is available, Otherwise a general non-styled format or one from the journal printer (here Springer) that presents formulas and graphs efficiently could be chosen. From there it is up to the editors.